# Seeding data for acceptance testing of AWS Serverless application

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, automated-tests, serverless, acceptance-testing

I'm starting to teach myself serverless development, using AWS Lambda and the Serverless CLI. So far, all is going great. However, I've got a snag with acceptance testing.

What I'm doing so far is:

- Deploy stack to AWS with a generated stage name - I'm using the CI job ID for this
- Run all the tests against this deployment
- Remove the deployment
- Deploy the stack to AWS with the "Dev" stage name

This is fine, until I need some data.

Testing endpoints without data is easy - that's the default state. So I can test that `GET /users/badid` returns a 404.

What's the typical way of setting up test data for the tests?

In my normal development I do this by running a full stack - UI, services, databases - in a local docker compose stack and the tests can talk to them directly. Is that the process to follow here - Have the tests talk directly to the varied AWS data stores? If so, how do you handle multiple (DynamoDB) tables across different CF stacks, e.g. for testing the UI?

If that's not the normal way to do it, what is?

Also, is there a standard way to clear out data between tests? I can't safely test a search endpoint if the data isn't constant for that test, for example. (If data isn't cleared out then the data in the system will be dependent on the order the tests run in, which is bad)

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Since, this is about Acceptance tests - those should be designed to care less of the architecture (tech side) and more of the business value. After all, such tests are supposed to be Black box. Speaking from experience with both, SLS or mSOA, the test setup and challenges are quite similar.

> What's the typical way of setting up test data for the tests?

There are many ways/patterns to do the job here, depending on your context. The ones that most worked for me are:

- [Database Sandbox](http://xunitpatterns.com/Database%20Sandbox.html) to provide a separate test database for each test run.
- [Table Truncation Teardown](http://xunitpatterns.com/Table%20Truncation%20Teardown.html) which truncates the tables modified during the test to tear down the fixture.
- [Fixture Setup Patterns](http://xunitpatterns.com/Fixture%20Setup%20Patterns.html) will help you build your prerequisites depending of test run needs

You can look at [Fixture Teardown Patterns](http://xunitpatterns.com/Fixture%20Teardown%20Patterns.html) for a

> standard way to clear out data between tests

Maybe, you don't need to

> Have the tests talk directly to the varied AWS data stores

as you might create an unrealistic state, if you can just hit the APIs/endpoints to do the job for you. For example, instead of managing multiple DynamoDB instances' `PutItem` calls - simply hit the `register` new user API. More info on Back door manipulation layer [here](http://automationisking.blogspot.com/2015/10/back-door-manipulation-api-layer.html).